# Generate identity variable from dummy indicators in Stata

Tags: foreach, stata

I working on somebody's dataset in Stata that uses dummy variables to indicate the subject id like the following:

```
variable name        variable label
country_dummy1         Afghanistan
country_dummy2         Albania
country_dummy3         Algeria
...
```

This makes the dataset very hard to work with and I am trying to generate a subject id variable (*country*) from the dummies to look like this

```
country        country_dummy1  country_dummy2  country_dummy3
Afghanistan         1               0                0
Albania             0               1                0
Algeria             0               0                1
```

I wrote the following command:

```
gen country = "."
foreach x of varlist country_dummy1-country_dummy175 {
local z : variable label `x'
replace country = `z'  if `x'==1
}
```

Stata produced the following error message:

```
Afghanistan not found
r(111);
```

I have not been able to identify why this occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
gen country = ""
foreach x of varlist country_dummy1-country_dummy175 {
    local z : variable label `x'
    replace country = "`z'"  if `x'==1
}
```

Note that Stata does not treat `"."` as a missing string value. Your error was that if you do not specify that you want a literal string with `""` then Stata will look for a variable with the name you specify. In your case, `Afghanistan` would be a legal variable name, but you have no such variable: hence the error. Countries with spaces in their names would be problematic for other reasons as well, but the command would almost always fail for the same reason.

This should work too:

```
gen country = ""
foreach x of varlist country_dummy1-country_dummy175 {
    replace country = "`: variable label `x''" if `x'
}
```

You could slap `quietly` on the `foreach` to avoid 175 messages from the `replace`.

Comment: Thank you, Nick! Appreciate your help!